# Azure AD Enterprise App SAML configuration

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure a SAML non-gallery Enterprise app and am having a problem with configuring the claims.  To summarize the current claims, `objectGUID` is being sent as the name identifier.  They send `extensionAttribute6` as `OrgID`.  `GivenName`, `sn` and `e-mail` address are sent without any changes.

AD Connect has been configured to sync `objectGUID` and `extensionAttribute6` to AAD, and those attributes are available in the SSO configuration blade for the Enterprise App.

My questions are:

1)  Does a Namespace need to be defined for the `objectGUID`, or can it just be selected from the source attribute in the claim and name identifier?

2)  How to transform the `extensionAttribute6` to be `OrgID`?

The current claim rules in ADFS are:

1)

> c:[Type ==
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname",
>   Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
>   => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("GUID"), query = ";objectGuid;{0}", param = c.Value);

2)

> c:[Type == "GUID"]
>   => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
>   Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value,
>   ValueType = c.ValueType,
>   Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"]
>   = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified");

3)

> c:[Type ==
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname",
>   Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
>   => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("givenName", "sn", "OrgID", "mail"), query =
>   ";givenName,sn,extensionAttribute6,mail;{0}", param = c.Value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to specify the namespace when you are mapping the User.ObjectID as the NameID claim. Also note that do not select any NameID Format and keep that as Default. Azure AD does support the pairwise Name Identifier. That means if the Service Provider is sending the NameID Format then the app will get that from Azure AD based on the Format specified in the SAML Request.

If you are trying to map the User.ObjectID claim as another claim then you can add the Namespace value as needed but it based on how the app need that back.

About transforming OrgID I Am not sure what you want to send. You can define that as a claim name and then select the ExtensionAttribute 6 as value and if the value exist for the user then you should see that in the SAML Response.

I hope this helps.

Thanks and Regards,

Jeevan Desarda